# A basic question on metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose In a metric space for every $x,y \in A$, for each $\epsilon$ we can find $x_0,y_0 \in B$ such that $$d(x,y) < \epsilon + d(x_0,y_0)$$

I want to prove that sup $d(x,y)_{x,y \in A}$ $\leq$ sup $d(x_0,y_0)_{x_0,y_0 \in B}$. 
I understand this because $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrary small. But, how to prove it formally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$\sup_{x,y\in A} d(x,y) \le \sup_{x,y\in B} d(x,y)+\varepsilon$$
for each $\varepsilon>0$.

Now take the limit $\varepsilon\to0^+$ on both sites of the inequality. Since non-strict inequality is preserved by limit, you get
$$\sup_{x,y\in A} d(x,y) \le \sup_{x,y\in B} d(x,y).$$